# Python Heatmap from csv

Tags: python, csv, heatmap

I've seen some examples on how to do a heatmap but I crashed my head against the wall more than once, since I don't really know how my .csv file has to look like to be usable for creation of a heat map. The one I'm trying to visualize looks like the following:
[image]

I've seen solutions with numpy and matplotlib that looked really nice, but I always failed at the conversion of my .csv to a usable format. If anyone could show/tell me where/how to make it usable, that'd be great.

Answer (score 7):

You could easily use pandas and its **read_csv** function to read the file and indeed matplot to plot the heat map.

The first column (index column) may be the thing that is causing you trouble. You could either delete it (and use panda's brand new indexes) from you data, or, when you call the function, use it as your index_col in the read_csv function.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path_to_csv= "insert here the path to your csv file"
df= pd.read_excel(path_to_csv ,index_col=0)

plt.imshow(df,cmap='hot',interpolation='nearest')

plt.show()
```

I tried this script here with your data and it worked,

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that [0.0, 0.1, ..., 1.0] are the specific positions on your x- and y-axis for which you are giving the "heat"-values in your .csv-file:

```
# Content of "data.csv"
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
7, 8, 5, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
....
```

You render the heatmap in IPython or Jupyter with:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",")
plt.imshow(data, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Right now the axis tick labels go from 0 to 10 rather than from 0.0 to 1.0, but you can relabel the axes if you want.

If you're using a .csv-file that looks exactly like the one in your picture when opened in Excel (with the column and row headers):

```
data = np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",", skip_header=True, usecols=range(1, 11))
```

Cheers,
Silas